How can I combine or derive a Shape from two Shapes, or outlines, in compose?
In case of the question is just the wrong approach; this is what I want to achieve:

In the image/example this is done by doing two Modifier.clip() sequentially, I want to get the same effect from a Shape so that I can pass it with M3's Shapes class.

Can I do it by combining two shapes?
Can I do it by combining two outlines?

or if that isn't possible

How do I create this custom shape?


Easiest way to combine 2 Shapes without drawing desired shape manually is using Path operations. You can also draw it inside a Path with lines and arcTo as well. But for a complex shapes than these 2 it would be difficult.
@Preview
@Composable
fun ShapeCombineTest() {

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp, 100.dp)
                .drawWithCache {

                    val cutoutOutline =
                        CutCornerShape(bottomStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp).createOutline(
                            size,
                            layoutDirection,
                            density
                        )

                    val roundedCornerOutline =
                        RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, bottomEnd = 16.dp).createOutline(
                            size,
                            layoutDirection,
                            density
                        )

                    val path1 = Path().apply {
                        addOutline(cutoutOutline)
                    }

                    val path2 = Path().apply {
                        addOutline(roundedCornerOutline)
                    }

                    val diffPath = Path.combine(
                        operation = PathOperation.Intersect,
                        path1 = path1,
                        path2 = path2
                    )

                    onDrawBehind {
                        drawPath(diffPath, Color.Red)
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}

Result

You can also turn this into shape to use with border or shadow as well

@Preview
@Composable
fun ShapeCombineTest() {

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    val shape = remember {
        GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->
            val cutoutOutline =
                CutCornerShape(bottomStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp).createOutline(
                    size,
                    layoutDirection,
                    density
                )

            val roundedCornerOutline =
                RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, bottomEnd = 16.dp).createOutline(
                    size,
                    layoutDirection,
                    density
                )

            val path1 = Path().apply {
                addOutline(cutoutOutline)
            }

            val path2 = Path().apply {
                addOutline(roundedCornerOutline)
            }

            addPath(
                Path.combine(
                    operation = PathOperation.Intersect,
                    path1 = path1,
                    path2 = path2
                )
            )
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp, 100.dp)
                .shadow(8.dp, shape)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Green, shape)
                .background(Color.Red, shape)
        )
    }
}

With M3 Composables

@Preview
@Composable
fun ShapeCombineTest() {

    val density = LocalDensity.current


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        OutlinedCard(
            shape = FusedShape(density),

            ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp, 100.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("M3 Card")
            }
        }

        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))

        ElevatedCard(
            shape = FusedShape(
                density = density,
                topStart = CornerShape.CutCorner(16.dp),
                topEnd = CornerShape.CutCorner(16.dp),
                bottomStart = CornerShape.RoundedCorner(16.dp),
                bottomEnd = CornerShape.RoundedCorner(16.dp)
            )
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp, 100.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("M3 Card")
            }
        }

        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))

        ElevatedCard(
            shape = FusedShape(
                density = density,
                topStart = CornerShape.RoundedCorner(16.dp),
                topEnd = CornerShape.CutCorner(16.dp),
                bottomStart = CornerShape.RoundedCorner(16.dp),
                bottomEnd = CornerShape.CutCorner(16.dp)
            ),
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp, 100.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("M3 Card")
            }
        }

        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            shape = FusedShape(density),
            onClick = {

            }
        ) {
            Text("M3 Button")
        }
    }
}

sealed class CornerShape(val radius: Dp) {
    class CutCorner(cornerRadius: Dp) : CornerShape(cornerRadius)
    class RoundedCorner(cornerRadius: Dp) : CornerShape(cornerRadius)
}

private fun FusedShape(
    density: Density,
    topStart: CornerShape = CornerShape.RoundedCorner(16.dp),
    topEnd: CornerShape = CornerShape.CutCorner(16.dp),
    bottomStart: CornerShape = CornerShape.CutCorner(16.dp),
    bottomEnd: CornerShape = CornerShape.RoundedCorner(16.dp),
) =
    GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->

        val cutCornerTopStart =
            if (topStart is CornerShape.CutCorner) topStart.radius else 0.dp
        val cutCornerTopEnd =
            if (topEnd is CornerShape.CutCorner) topEnd.radius else 0.dp
        val cutCornerBottomStart =
            if (bottomStart is CornerShape.CutCorner) bottomStart.radius else 0.dp
        val cutCornerBottomEnd =
            if (bottomEnd is CornerShape.CutCorner) bottomEnd.radius else 0.dp

        val roundedCornerTopStart =
            if (topStart is CornerShape.RoundedCorner) topStart.radius else 0.dp
        val roundedCornerTopEnd =
            if (topEnd is CornerShape.RoundedCorner) topEnd.radius else 0.dp
        val roundedCornerBottomStart =
            if (bottomStart is CornerShape.RoundedCorner) bottomStart.radius else 0.dp
        val roundedCornerBottomEnd =
            if (bottomEnd is CornerShape.RoundedCorner) bottomEnd.radius else 0.dp

        val cutoutOutline =
            CutCornerShape(
                topStart = cutCornerTopStart,
                topEnd = cutCornerTopEnd,
                bottomStart = cutCornerBottomStart,
                bottomEnd = cutCornerBottomEnd
            )
                .createOutline(
                    size,
                    layoutDirection,
                    density
                )

        val roundedCornerOutline =
            RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = roundedCornerTopStart,
                topEnd = roundedCornerTopEnd,
                bottomStart = roundedCornerBottomStart,
                bottomEnd = roundedCornerBottomEnd
            ).createOutline(
                size,
                layoutDirection,
                density
            )

        val path1 = Path().apply {
            addOutline(cutoutOutline)
        }

        val path2 = Path().apply {
            addOutline(roundedCornerOutline)
        }

        addPath(
            Path.combine(
                operation = PathOperation.Intersect,
                path1 = path1,
                path2 = path2
            )
        )
    }

Extra
Blending shapes and shape drawings in png files
If these were 2 images of shapes, if at least one of them cover dimensions of other,  it's quite easy applying one BlendMode as in link below. To apply blend mode on other in most cases the one that blend mode applied should cover at least each other or section operation should be applied.
How to clip or cut a Composable?
But if none of these do not cover full canvas or required source you need to use intermediary Rectangle to get intersections and remove combination of intersection from another rect.
@Composable
private fun ShapeFusionBox() {

    val density = LocalDensity.current

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(200.dp, 100.dp)
            .graphicsLayer {
                compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
            }
            .drawWithCache {
                val cutoutOutline =
                    CutCornerShape(bottomStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp).createOutline(
                        size,
                        layoutDirection,
                        density
                    )

                val roundedCornerOutline =
                    RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, bottomEnd = 16.dp).createOutline(
                        size,
                        layoutDirection,
                        density
                    )

                onDrawBehind {

                    // You can draw with painter or ImageBitmap here
                    drawOutline(
                        outline = roundedCornerOutline,
                        color = Color.Blue
                    )

                    // You can draw with painter or ImageBitmap here
                    drawOutline(
                        outline = cutoutOutline,
                        color = Color.Blue,
                        blendMode = BlendMode.Xor
                    )

                    drawRect(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        blendMode = BlendMode.SrcOut
                    )
                }
            }
    )
}


Great response, thank you! I am missing a very small thing, hope you know the answer. Do you know how I can create the shape without access to @Composable?
Also, Shape (Generic Shape) can not be passed into the m3 Shapes constructor, it requires CornerBasedShapes.
So, can this non composable function be created?
fun CutRoundCornerShape(cutSize: Dp, roundSize: Dp): CornerBasedShape

You don't need to access @Composable for creating a shape, remember in my example is for not creating same shape on every recomposition for demonstration. You can turn block inside remember in second sample into a function that returns Shape. M3 Composabe's take Shape as param, which function take CornerBasedShape?

val density = LocalDensity.current requires @Composable, and then I also found out that Shapes requires CornerBasedShape (Not Shape / GenericShape) - that was somewhat covered in the question but not obvious.

The post by @Thracian made me investigate their code, and then combined it with the code for CutCornerShape and RoundedCornerShape.
Here's the SemiRoundCutCornerShape
fun SemiRoundCutCornerShape(size: Dp, roundedLeft: Boolean = true) = SemiRoundCutCornerShape(size, size, roundedLeft)

fun SemiRoundCutCornerShape(cutSize: Dp, roundSize: Dp, roundedLeft: Boolean = true) = SemiRoundCutCornerShape(
    topStart = CornerSize(roundSize),
    topEnd = CornerSize(cutSize),
    bottomEnd = CornerSize(roundSize),
    bottomStart = CornerSize(cutSize),
    roundedLeft = roundedLeft
)

class SemiRoundCutCornerShape(
    topStart: CornerSize,
    topEnd: CornerSize,
    bottomEnd: CornerSize,
    bottomStart: CornerSize,
    private val roundedLeft: Boolean = true
) : CornerBasedShape(
    topStart = topStart,
    topEnd = topEnd,
    bottomEnd = bottomEnd,
    bottomStart = bottomStart,
) {

    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        topStart: Float,
        topEnd: Float,
        bottomEnd: Float,
        bottomStart: Float,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection
    ): Outline {
        val roundOutline: Outline = Outline.Rounded(
            when (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr && roundedLeft) {
                true -> RoundRect(
                    rect = size.toRect(),
                    topLeft = CornerRadius(if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) topStart else topEnd),
                    bottomRight = CornerRadius(if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) bottomEnd else bottomStart),
                )
                false -> RoundRect(
                    rect = size.toRect(),
                    topRight = CornerRadius(if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) topEnd else topStart),
                    bottomLeft = CornerRadius(if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) bottomStart else bottomEnd)
                )
            }
        )
        val cutOutline: Outline = Outline.Generic(
            when (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr && roundedLeft) {
                true -> Path().apply {
                    var cornerSize = 0F
                    moveTo(0f, cornerSize)
                    lineTo(cornerSize, 0f)
                    cornerSize = topEnd
                    lineTo(size.width - cornerSize, 0f)
                    lineTo(size.width, cornerSize)
                    cornerSize = 0F
                    lineTo(size.width, size.height - cornerSize)
                    lineTo(size.width - cornerSize, size.height)
                    cornerSize = bottomStart
                    lineTo(cornerSize, size.height)
                    lineTo(0f, size.height - cornerSize)
                    close()
                }
                false -> Path().apply {
                    var cornerSize = topEnd
                    moveTo(0f, cornerSize)
                    lineTo(cornerSize, 0f)
                    cornerSize = 0F
                    lineTo(size.width - cornerSize, 0f)
                    lineTo(size.width, cornerSize)
                    cornerSize = bottomStart
                    lineTo(size.width, size.height - cornerSize)
                    lineTo(size.width - cornerSize, size.height)
                    cornerSize = 0F
                    lineTo(cornerSize, size.height)
                    lineTo(0f, size.height - cornerSize)
                    close()
                }
            }

        )

        return Outline.Generic(Path.combine(
            operation = PathOperation.Intersect,
            path1 = Path().apply { addOutline(cutOutline) },
            path2 = Path().apply { addOutline(roundOutline) }
        ))
    }

    override fun copy(
        topStart: CornerSize,
        topEnd: CornerSize,
        bottomEnd: CornerSize,
        bottomStart: CornerSize
    ): CornerBasedShape = SemiRoundCutCornerShape(
        topStart = topStart,
        topEnd = topEnd,
        bottomEnd = bottomEnd,
        bottomStart = bottomStart
    )

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "SemiRoundCutShape(topStart = $topStart, topEnd = $topEnd, bottomEnd = " +
                "$bottomEnd, bottomStart = $bottomStart)"
    }
}

Here used to create
SemiRoundCutCornerShape(8.dp)
SemiRoundCutCornerShape(24.dp, roundedLeft = false)
SemiRoundCutCornerShape(16.dp)
SemiRoundCutCornerShape(
  topStart = CornerSize(60.dp),
  topEnd = CornerSize(8.dp),
  bottomEnd = CornerSize(16.dp),
  bottomStart = CornerSize(20.dp)
)


